# How to order by sum

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

is there a way to order a query by the sum of 2 or more columns? I want to make a top based by the sum of some rows [numeric]

Comment: confusing question... do you want to sum two or more columns in a single row? or sum some values in some rows?

Answer (score 7):

```
select num1, num2
from mytable
order by num1+num2 desc
```

Comment: correct juergen - edited thanks.  also consider LIMIT clause for top n results.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Col1, Col2,...,Coln
FROM table
ORDER BY Col1+Col2+...+Coln DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your server you may not be able to use expressions in the ORDER BY. You also may need to include that ordering column in the SELECT list.